# Using BUILDARGS to substitute a class in a Role

Tags: perl, moose

I use a Perl Moose Role (`Import::Git::Role`) as an Abstract Base Class to share common behaviour between a Class an actual implementation of functionality (`Import::Git`) and a Class that performs some logging instead (`Import::Git::dryrun`).

I would like the dryrun class to be transparent. I want to create a object like this:

```
   my $git = Import::Git->new( dryrun => $dryrun );
```

The variable dryrun could be 0 or 1. If it is 1, I would like to construct an `Import::Git::dryrun` object instead, basically replacing the `Import::Git` object with it. Thats intended because they share all methods via the role.

I have tried to exchange the Object during the BUILDARGS Method like this:

```
around BUILDARGS => sub {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     my $orig  = shift;
     my $class = shift;

     my %args = ( @_ == 1 ? %{ $_[ 0 ] } : @_ );

     if ( !%args || $args{ 'dryrun' } != 1 ) {
         return $class->$orig( @_ );
     }
     else {
         return Import::Git::dryrun->$orig( @_ );
    }
};
```

but this doesn't achieve what I am trying to do, it constructs the old class:

```
  DB<1> x Import::Git->new( dryrun => 1 )
0  Import::Git=HASH(0x2fd9210)
   'dryrun' => 1
  DB<2> x Import::Git->new()
0  Import::Git=HASH(0x301dbb8)
   'dryrun' => 0
  DB<3>
```

I thought I would probably have to call the new Method of the dryrun-method so I made the following exchange:

```
   # change this:
   return Import::Git::dryrun->$orig( @_ );
   # to this
   return Import::Git::dryrun->new( @_ );
```

But it returns `BUILDARGS did not return a HASH reference`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Naw, no need to create an entire class. Just use the sub I posted. (Moved to an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a constructor build a different class than the one requested is icky. I wouldn't take the approach you did even if it did work. I would use

```
sub factory {
   my ($class, %opts) = @_;
   return $opt{dryrun} ? $class.'::dryrun' : $class;
}

Import::Git->factory( dryrun => $dryrun )->new( ... )
```

or

```
sub instantiate {
   my ($class, %opts) = @_;
   return ( delete($opt{dryrun}) ? $class.'::dryrun' : $class )->new(%opts);
}

Import::Git->instantiate( dryrun => $dryrun, ... )
```

Comment: valid argument. That way someone could create an Import::Git(dryrun => 1) if desired. I like the instantiate subroutine :)

Comment: You could, but then you'd lose the ability to do `Import::Git::Subclass->instantiate(...)`

Answer (score 2):

`BUILDARGS` is used to manipulate the argument list you pass to the objects constructor before the object is created so will have no impact on what new returns. Instead of `around BUILDARGS` you might want to try `around new`, then you can replace the object returned by new with your dry run object.